# Какие существуют методы решения кубических уравнений (4 параметра)?

Tags: математика

В интернете есть решения, но они все хаотично разбросаны без структуризации по методам. Мне важно самому понять один метод и начать его использовать для решения.

Comment: Аналитический метод только один - метод Кардано. Все остальные методы - либо чисельные (ищут корни с заданной точностью), либо решают частные случаи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Формула Кардано](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE), например :)
Вот еще одна [ссылка](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[ax%5E3%2Bbx%5E2%2Bcx%2Bd%3D%3D0,x]).

Или вас интересует численное решение? Поскольку один корень **всегда** существует, находите его численно - хоть простым половинным делением, далее приводите уравнение третьей степени к уравнению второго, а там уж все просто.

Чтобы выяснить, где именно искать первый корень - можно воспользоваться [отделением действительных корней алгебраических уравнений](https://old.math.tsu.ru/EEResources/cm/text/2_4.htm).

Такой ответ устраивает? Если нет - то переформулируйте свой вопрос...

Comment: _Поскольку один корень **всегда** существует_ - в общем случае утверждение ошибочно. Вырожденное кубическое уравнение (коэффициент при кубе равен нулю) может не иметь действительных корней.

Comment: @Akina такое уравнение математики не называют кубическим

Answer (score 3):

Наилучший вариант - угадать один из корней, а потом получить квадратное уравнение для остальных корней. Если уравнение с целыми коэффициентами, то можно поделить младший коэффициент на старший и поискать корни среди положительных и отрицательных делителей этого отношения. Например, возвратное уравнение 
**ax<sup>3</sup>+bx<sup>2</sup>+bx+a=0** имеет корень **x= -1**.

Если наивная попытка не удалась, то следует перейти от общего уравнения **ax<sup>3</sup>+bx<sup>2</sup>+сx+d=0** к приведённому **y<sup>3</sup>+py+q=0**, и в этом поможет подстановка **x=y-b/(3a)**.

Для приведенного кубического уравнения обычно предлагается формула Кардано. А можно и напрямую воспользоваться подстановкой Тартальи:
**y=u+v**, **u<sup>3</sup>+v<sup>3</sup>+(3uv+p)(u+v)+q=0**, **3uv+p=0**,
которая приводит к системе уравнений на сумму и произведение кубов:
**u<sup>3</sup>+v<sup>3</sup> = - q, u<sup>3</sup>v<sup>3</sup> = - p<sup>3</sup>/27**.
Обратная теорема Виета даёт для этих кубов квадратное уравнение вида **w<sup>2</sup> + qw - p<sup>3</sup>/27 = 0** и в конечном итоге - известную формулу Кардано. Но иногда значения **u<sup>3</sup>** и **v<sup>3</sup>** можно просто подобрать.

Заметим, что при отрицательных значениях **p** дискриминант  **q<sup>2</sup>/4+p<sup>3</sup>/27** может оказаться отрицательным. На этот случай существуют формулы тройного аргумента для тригонометрических и гиперболических функций
**cos 3t = 4cos<sup>3</sup> t - 3cos t; ch 3t = 4ch<sup>3</sup> t - 3ch t**, где **ch t = (e<sup>t</sup> + e<sup>-t</sup>)/2**.
Поэтому для уравнения **4z<sup>3</sup> - 3r<sup>2</sup>z = s** при **s <= r<sup>3</sup>** можно получить:
**t<sub>k</sub> = 1/3arccos(s/r<sup>3</sup>)+(2k/3)pi, z<sub>k</sub>=r cost<sub>k</sub>, k= 0, 1, 2**.
Если **s > r<sup>3</sup>**, то решение единственное, и его можно выразить аналогичным образом через гиперболические функции. Здесь пригодится формула **arch q = ln(q+sqrt(q<sup>2</sup>-1))**.

Таким образом, решения кубического уравнения всегда можно выразить через элементарные функции действительного аргумента.

Answer (score 1):

Численно решается [методом Ньютона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), сходимость метода квадратичная, в отличие от метода дихотомии предлагаемой @Harry, который имеет линейную сходимость.

Comment: Только даже в Википедии показан как [контрпример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B) решение кубического уравнения методом Ньютона при плохих начальных условиях... Метод дихотомии обладает тем ценным свойством, что для непрерывной функции всегда дает решение с заранее заданной точностью `eps` за `log_2((b-a)/eps)` шагов. Когда что-то известно о корне заранее - дело другое...